# Move specific directories from certain depth

Tags: bash, files, osx, mv

I've tried to make a bash script that will help me move specific subfolders from my folder.
The issue is,in the main folder `photos` I have folders named like this: 
`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`0` and inside them the folders with exact name repeat,and then again the same folder structure repeats. The subfolders I want to move are in the last folder with one character in their name.The subfolders I want to move have 2 or more characters in their name. Folder structure is `0-9`/`0-9`/`0-9`/subdir
The destination folder isn't specified,so let's say it is `desktop/photos1`.

Example: `photos/0/0/0/23345` `photos/1/9/0/12578`

If two subdirectories have the same name e.g. `photos/0/0/0/23345` and `photos/1/1/1/23345` I would like to rename one of them. I'm on OSX

Comment: I would like to rename one of them

Comment: Yes the depth is always,photos/name/name/name/somedir in my case the "name" has one character 0-9 and subdir always has more than 2 characters in his name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On systems with GNU coreutils (so not a default installation of OSX), you could use

  ```
  mv -f --backup=numbered -t /path/to/target photos/*/*/*/*/
  ```

  This will move *all* subdirs at depth 4 under `photos/`, whatever the names of the dirs at depths 1, 2, and 3.

  The advantage of this method: renaming will happen only as needed (if you have only one `12578` subfolder, e.g. in `photos/1/9/0/`, it will not be renamed).
- Without GNU coreutils, you can use this (somewhat convoluted) script, which will rename all subfolders. E.g. `photos/1/9/0/12578` will be renamed `12578-190`:

  ```
  target=/some/path
  for i in {0..9}; do
    for j in {0..9}; do
      for k in {0..9}; do
        for dir in "photos/$i/$j/$k/*/"; do
          mv -- "$dir" "$target/$(basename $dir)-$i$j$k"
        done
      done
    done
  done
  ```

Comment: I'm getting this error     mv: rename 1027999 to /photos1/photos 1027999-9: No such file or directory

Comment: In `target` you must put the full path of your dir, something like `/home/<username>/desktop/photos1`, and this dir must exist. Now, I really don't see how that /space/ could appear: "photos 1027999-9". Please, double-check your typing.

Comment: now only thing that was moved are folders from 0/0/0/ the rest isn't moved,other like example : 1/2/3/ are not moved

Comment: This is weird. Are you sure your shell is bash? Type `echo {0..9}`, the output should be `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Comment: It seems i'v made a mistake explaining. Folders that were moved are only from 0/0/0 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 to 9/9/9 but all the folders like 1/2/3 2/1/9 aren't moved. Yes my shell is bash

Comment: @don_crissti: if I do `for dir in photos/$i/$i/$i/*/` I will have to do `mv $dir $target/$(basename $dir)-$i`. I thought the other way would be easier to understand for a newbie. (Also, thanks for the `*/` thing, I over-interpreted the request as saying there were only subdirs in the one-digit dirs.)

Comment: @OneStyle07: yes your question is more than ambiguous, you stated "inside them the folders with exact name repeat" and you give examples `0/0/0` and `1/1/1`! don_crissti's answer assumes the same.

Comment: Yes i'm on OSX.

Comment: I'v made a mistake explaining the folder structure,like you said with this script the 1/1/1/subdir will be moved. Folder structure is 0-9/0-9/0-9/subdir  so every folder,0-9 has 0-9 inside,like for example 1/9/2/subdir